# Jackson automatically map properties named @foo?

Tags: java, json, jackson

When playing with REST, my provider is generating JSON with attribute names starting with an at sign when the property is marked as @XmlAttibute like this:

```
@XmlAttribute
int foo = 1;
```

will return

```
{"@foo":1}
```

How can I tell Jackson for deserializing that if I have on the client

```
int foo;
```

that it should take the json-Attribute @foo for this. Or in more general terms: how to tell Jackson to ignore the @ when deserializing?

Update: I know about @JsonProperty("@foo") annotation that StaxMan is referring - I forgot to put that in my original question, as I was especially interested in a "global setting" and not on a per property level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiesti thing might be to disable adding those '@' signs there as they seem useless. I know some XML-to-JSON libs (Jettison) want to use this to differentiate between XML attributes and elements, but it's of little use with actual JSON processing.

But Jackson can be given expected property name in JSON with @JsonProperty annotation:

```
@JsonProperty("@foo")
public int foo; // or add in setter
```

if it is necessary to keep those at signs in there.

Comment: I know about the @JsonProperty annotation for this - but the I forgot to add this to my question. I was more interested in a "global setting". But good to know that this is a jettison "feature".

Comment: Ok. Then you might be interested in "custom naming strategies" (1.8), http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/03/entry_448.html. It might be tricky if only some properties have at sign, but if you can easily identify those it could work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `@XmlElement` rather than `@XmlAttribute`. Values for the latter are always given a @ at the beginning.